# I got error deprecated conversion froms string constant to char ? can anyone fix this for me ? thanks

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define MaxV 20 //Define su dung cho so dinh cuc dai cua do thi

 
int A[MaxV][MaxV];      //Ma tran ke

int V = 0;                          //So dinh cua do thi

int ChuaXet[MaxV];

 int DinhTruoc[MaxV];
 
//Thu tuc nhap matran ke bang ban phim.

void NhapMTKe(int A[][MaxV],int &V)

{
    cout << "Nhap V :";
     //printf("Nhap V:");
    cin >> V;
     //scanf("%d", &V);
    int i;
     for ( i=0; i<V; i++)

     {
                int j;
                 for ( j=0; j<V; j++)

                 {
                    cout << "A[" << i+1 << "," << j+1 << "] = " ;
                    //printf("A[%d,%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
                    cin >> A[i][j];
                    //scanf("%d", &(A[i][j]));
                 }
     }
}

 
// Xuat ket qua ma tran ke cua do thi ra man hinh.

void XuatMTKe(int A[][MaxV], int V)

{

     printf("\nMa tran ke:\n");
    int i;
     for ( i=0; i<V; i++)

     {
                int j;
                 for ( j=0; j<V; j++)
                                cout << A[i][j];
                             //printf("%3d ", A[i][j]);

                cout << endl;

     }

}

 
//Doc du lieu ma tran ke cua do thi da duoc tao thanh file text luu san tren dia.

int DocMTKe(char *fileName, int A[][MaxV], int &V)
{

     FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");

     if (f == NULL)

     {

                 cout <<"Doc file loi !!!";

                 return 0;

     }

     fscanf(f, "%d", &V);
    int i;
     for ( i=0; i < V; i++)

     {
                int j;
                 for ( j=0; j < V; j++)

                 {

                             fscanf(f, "%d", &(A[i][j]));

                 }

     }

     return 1;

}

void DFS(int v)

{
    int u;
    int nSoTPLT = 0;
     ChuaXet[v] = nSoTPLT;

     for (  u=0; u<V; u++ )

                 if ( A[v][u]!=0 )                       //The hien u la dinh ke cua v

                             if ( ChuaXet[u]==0 )

                             {

                                         DinhTruoc[u]  = v;

                                         DFS( u );         //Dinh u chua duoc duyet qua==> Duyet u

                             }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

     int nSoTPLT = 0;

 
     DocMTKe("D:\\3.txt", A, V);

     XuatMTKe(A, V);

 
     int s, t;

     //printf("Nhap dinh bat dau, dinh ket thuc:");scanf("%d",&s);scanf("%d",&t);
     cout<<"Nhap dinh bat dau, dinh ket thuc:";  cin>> s >> t;

     s--;   t--;

     DFS(s);

 
     int DuongDi[MaxV], k = 0;

     DuongDi[k++] = t;

     while ( DinhTruoc[ DuongDi[k-1] ] != s)

                 DuongDi[k++] = DinhTruoc[ DuongDi[k-1] ];

     DuongDi[k++] = s;

    //printf("\nDuong di tu %d den %d la :",s,t);
     cout<<"\nDuong di tu "<<s<<" den "<<t<<" la: ";
     int i;
     for ( i=k-1; i>=0; i-- )

                //printf("%d",DuongDi[i]+1);
                 cout<< DuongDi[i]+1 <<"  ";

     
}
```

Can anyone fix this for me? thanks
Its the finding  path code in graph

it is giving me the following error:

`deprecated conversion from string constant to char*`

I used dev c++

input : 3.txt:

```
5

0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
```

i need to add some words :
llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `int DocMTKe(char *fileName, int A[][MaxV], int &V)` -> `int DocMTKe(char const *fileName, int A[][MaxV], int &V)`

Comment: Note: Padding a question with garbage is often the kiss of death for a question. Stack Overflow is trying to tell you that you have a lot of code for what looks like a a little  problem and you should instead build a smaller code example. Often by examining the problem in a smaller example, you can find the solution yourself and eliminate the need for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `DocMTKe` function to take `const char*`:

```
int DocMTKe(const char *fileName, int A[][MaxV], int &V)
```

You get the error because type of a string literal like: `"D:\\3.txt"` is `const char[]` and it is not allowed to convert it `char *` (non const), but you can convert it to `const char*`.